# How to get prefix table in magento 2

Tags: prefix, magento2

I need to get prefix table in magento 2 to join with another table. I try to find on internet but I don't see how to get prefix table in magento 2. Can you help me

Comment: Pleas provide more details for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the prefix by using the function `getTableName()` like below :
Always use `getTableName` with raw queries to fetch the table along with the prefix dynamically

```
 protected $_resource;

 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{

    $connection  = $this->_resource->getConnection();
    $tableName   = $connection->getTableName('customer_entity'); // It will return "yourtableprefix_customer_entity"

    $mapsDeleteQuery = "your raw SQL Query";
    $connection->query($mapsDeleteQuery);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there have been some code changes in Magento. So now referring to @Manashvi Birla answer, you need to replace :

```
$connection->getTableName('customer_entity');
```

by :

```
$this->_resource->getTableName('customer_entity');
```

to be able to get the table prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Just open **env.php**. You can find env.php file under base_dir/app/etc/env.php

Here you can search keyword **table_prefix**.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your question but I want to get prefix table in to my code. Can you help me?